# If $ \log \log x =1$, then is it true that $e^e =x$?

Tags: logarithms

I worked out this question, and I wanted to see if my understanding of the concepts involved is sound.

Solve for $x$
$$\ln(\ln(x))=1$$

$$e^1=\ln(x)$$
$$e^e=x$$ Since any number raised to $1$ is just itself, the final answer could be expressed as $x=e^e$ This is not a homework question, but a question I stumbled across which I find interesting: I want to see if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: You could've checked that
$\log e^e = e\log e=e$, and then $\log e =1$, which is what you want.

Comment: Cool thanks, I didn't see that connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct. To verify, plug the answer back into the equation and check that both sides are equal:

\begin{align*}
\ln(\ln(e^e)) = \ln(e \ln(e)) = \ln(e \cdot 1) = \ln(e) = 1
\end{align*}

Remember that $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ and $\ln(e) = 1$.

Comment: is that $\ln(a^b)=b\ln(a)$ correct !!? for $b\in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @AbdelmajidKhadari Yes. It is a direct consequence of the definition of the logarithm.